# Как выровнять колонки по вертикали?

Tags: css

Имеется следующий код

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="review-wrap d-flex">
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <h3 class="review__title">Раздвижные электрические шторы</h3>   
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="review__img" src="img/review/review-1.jpg" alt="Раздвижные электрические шторы">
                        </a>
                        <p class="riview__text">Самые популярные изделия для которых характерно передвижение в горизонтальном направлении. Выглядят изящно, модно и способны прослужить более 10 лет</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <h3 class="review__title">Шторы плиссе</h3> 
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="review__img" src="img/review/review-2.jpg" alt="Шторы плиссе">
                        </a>
                        <p class="riview__text">Самые популярные изделия для которых характерно передвижение в горизонтальном направлении. Выглядят изящно, модно и способны прослужить более 10 лет</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <h3 class="review__title">Японские шторы</h3>   
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="review__img" src="img/review/review-3.jpg" alt="Раздвижные электрические шторы">
                        </a>
                        <p class="riview__text">Самые популярные изделия для которых характерно передвижение в горизонтальном направлении. Выглядят изящно, модно и способны прослужить более 10 лет</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <h3 class="review__title">Раздвижные
                        электрические шторы</h3>    
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="review__img" src="img/review/review-4.jpg" alt="Раздвижные электрические шторы">
                        </a>
                        <p class="riview__text">Самые популярные изделия для которых характерно передвижение в горизонтальном направлении. Выглядят изящно, модно и способны прослужить более 10 лет</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <h3 class="review__title">Шторы плиссе</h3> 
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="review__img" src="img/review/review-5.jpg" alt="Раздвижные электрические шторы">
                        </a>
                        <p class="riview__text">Самые популярные изделия для которых характерно передвижение в горизонтальном направлении. Выглядят изящно, модно и способны прослужить более 10 лет</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <h3 class="review__title">Японские шторы</h3>   
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="review__img" src="img/review/review-6.jpg" alt="Раздвижные электрические шторы">
                        </a>
                        <p class="riview__text">Самые популярные изделия для которых характерно передвижение в горизонтальном направлении. Выглядят изящно, модно и способны прослужить более 10 лет</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

И css

```
.review__title{
    max-width: 225px;
    padding: 22px 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.2;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.review-wrap{
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Вопрос как мне выровнять теперь контент по вертикали при переносе строки колонки сезжают вниз

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Самое простое решение указать у титула max-height. Вы должны понимать, что если текст заголовка будет в 5 строк всё равно всё поедет, так как фотографии должны быть одинакового размера, а браузер будет отодвигать текст и весь контент. Определите максимальное кол-во строк в заголовке и укажите max-height.

Comment: Да это решение помогло. Конечно не думаю что оно самое правильное

Comment: Просто нужно понимать что текстовый контент Вы не сможете вместить в фиксированный блок по высоте. Браузер автоматически отодвинет всё если что-то не влезает. Есть ещё в принципе решение (сейчас не могу его протестировать, так что вот теория) Делаете ваш col-lg.. флексом с direction колонка и далее justify-content: space-between. И сам этот итем фиксированной высотой. В результате должно произойти выравнивание.